# How do I convert a binary into a list of structs in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a binary as follows: `<<123, 249, 222, 67, 253, 128, 131, 231, 101>>`

And I'd like to transform it into a list of structs like this:

`[%RGB{red: 123, green: 249, blue: 222}, %RGB{red: 67, green: 253, blue: 128}, %RGB{red: 131, green: 231, blue: 101}]`.

The `RGB` struct is defined like this:

```elixir
defmodule RGB do
  defstruct red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0
end
```

I have tried the following method:

```elixir
  def to_rgb(data) when is_binary(data) do
    stage = 0 # R:0, G:1, B:2, 3:Complete
    rgb = %RGB{}
    rgblist = []
    for x <- :binary.bin_to_list(data) do
      cond do
        stage == 0 -> rgb = %{rgb | red: x}
        stage == 1 -> rgb = %{rgb | blue: x}
        stage == 2 -> rgb = %{rgb | green: x}
      end
      if stage == 3 do
        rgblist = rgblist ++ [rgb]
        stage = 0
      end
    end
    rgblist
  end
```

But it is far from elegant and doesn't work (the return value is an empty list).

Comment: "doesn't work (the return value is an empty list)" The reason why it doesn't work is because unlike imperative languages, (re)assigning a variable within `if`/`cond`/`for` has no effect, these blocks are expressions, not statements, and will just return a value. Variable scoping is briefly explained [here](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#if-and-unless).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the `r`, `g`, `b` values out of the binary 3 at a time using [bitstring generators](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1), and place them into the struct:

```elixir
def to_rgb(data) when is_binary(data) and rem(byte_size(data), 3) == 0 do
  for <<r, g, b <- data>> do
    %RGB{red: r, green: g, blue: b}
  end
end
```

Output:

```elixir
[
  %RGB{blue: 222, green: 249, red: 123},
  %RGB{blue: 128, green: 253, red: 67},
  %RGB{blue: 101, green: 231, red: 131}
]
```

Comment: Isn't the `rem(byte_size(data), 3) == 0` function guard technically unnecessary since it will MatchError anyway? Anyway, thank you for the solution.

Comment: Without the `byte_size` guard, any remainder bytes will be ignored. With the guard, you'll get a `FunctionClauseError` saying it doesn't match the guard.